# Failed to Start SQL Server Reporting Services in Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

When I start the SQL Server Reporting Services in the configuration manager, I get this error message:

> "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely
>   fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for
>   details"

I tried to Google it and I found the best solution is creating a ServicePipeTimeout in the regedit; however, after I have done it, the problem still remains the same... how can I fix this?

Comment: did you check the event log? if yes then whats the error on the event log?

Comment: is it this one? i search the "Event viewer" in start menu, after launch i click the "System", the it show a "information", when i double click it, it show in the general tabs and wrote "The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the running state"

Comment: if click the "Error", it show this "The SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER1) service failed to start due to the following error: 
Access is denied."

Comment: SSRS services is not running. check the security on the services on the log on tab. http://doc.zarafa.com/trunk/Free_Busy_Manual/en-US/html/images/service_prop_general.png